# vscode define select n lines shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some custom shortcuts to move with `cmd+up` and `cmd+down` with intervals of 5 lines.

```json
   {
        "key": "cmd+up",
        "command": "cursorMove",
        "args": {
            "to": "up",
            "by": "line",
            "value": 5
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+down",
        "command": "cursorMove",
        "args": {
            "to": "down",
            "by": "line",
            "value": 5
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
```

What I would like is when pressing `shift+cmd+[up,down]` **to select 5 lines up and down**. I've found that there are a few "commands" such as {`cursorDownSelect`,  `cursorPageDownSelect`, `CursorEndSelect`} but none of them allow me to define some args to jump a few lines, does anybody know how to do it ?

Comment: thanks @Mark worked like charm, post the answer so we can close this question ;) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `select` option to the `cursorMove` command.  Search for `cursorMove` at this commands page:  https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

```json
  {
        "key": "cmd+up",
        "command": "cursorMove",
        "args": {
            "to": "up",
            "by": "line",
            "value": 5
            "select": true       // the default is false
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+down",
        "command": "cursorMove",
        "args": {
            "to": "down",
            "by": "line",
            "value": 5,
            "select": true
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
```